# Installing PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 12

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.2, postgis

At the current moment, March 4th 2013, can PostGIS2.0 be install with PostgreSQL 9.2?

I checked [their website](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall#PostGIS2.0) and to my understanding it is not possible...

I hope that's not the case. Can anyone tell me and point out the instructions on how to install PostGIS 2.0 on PostgreSQL 9.2 on Ubuntu?

Comment: That page you link to was updated 4 weeks ago (specifically the Unbuntu section). There's not much reason to believe it is outdated. For this type of question, you're better off asking on a PostGIS forum/mailing list since it is very time-dependent. (i.e. not sure your question is a good fit for this site.)

Comment: If you build from source it probably is very possible. Just make sure to install postgresql 9.2 packages before building postgis. If there are no 9.2 packages for ubuntu you can build postgresql from source to.

Answer (score 1):

Just a followup: I just checked it and now there is a package called `postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.0`.  The problem is finally gone.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall reading recently you'd probably have to install both PostgreSQL and PostGIS from source in that case.

This isn't particularly difficult but you need to make sure you have all the appropriate development packages installed.  Often times this will be trial and error (run ./configure, see what it complains about, install the package, wash, rinse, repeat).

if you go this route, I highly recommend running ./configure --help and reading through all the options.  The PostgreSQL source is very configurable and this is easy.  From there, though, PostGIS should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks Mat, Eelke and @Chris Travers. I will try to install from source through trial and error.